# Why is ${52 \choose 19} {33\choose 1} \ne {52 \choose 20} $?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of choosing 19 cards that are not an ace and the 20th card is an ace from a deck of 52 standard cards?

The answer is apparently $$
\frac{{48 \choose 19} {4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 19} {33\choose 1}} 
$$

But I'm wondering, isn't this the same as:

$$
\frac{{48 \choose 19} {4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 20} } 
$$

?

My question is focused on the denominator (total outcomes) : Choosing 19 cards from 52 and then and then choosing 1 card from 33 should be the same as simply choosing 20 cards from 52, right?

But I worked out the math these two numbers are not equal.  So I'm confused as to why they are not equal (though it seems to me like they should be equal).

Comment: "Choosing 19 cards from 52 and then and then choosing 1 card from 33 should be the same as simply choosing 20 cards from 52, right?" This is a paralyzingly clever way to phrase your problem. But note that we could do the first thing in any order, whereas the second thing must be done all at once.

Comment: Good thinking mr count :)

Comment: @mick Ah! Ah! Ah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not the same. One could just insert and calculate, like you have done, but there is also a more intuitive argument: because the one-out-of-33 card you choose will be distinguished. What $\binom{52}{19}\binom{33}{1}$ actually equals is $\binom{52}{20}\binom{20}{1}$, which is picking the twenty cards, and then choosing one distinguished card from among those.